# My font does not appear in Network (reactjs, styled components)

Tags: reactjs, fonts, styled-components

I am actually blocked by an issue with the font import in a React project (working with styled-components).

This is my Fonts file:

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

import NameOfYourFontWoff from './ClickerScript.woff';
import NameOfYourFontWoff2 from './ClickerScript.woff2';

export default createGlobalStyle`
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Font Name';
        src: local('Font Name'), local('FontName'),
        url(${NameOfYourFontWoff2}) format('woff2'),
        url(${NameOfYourFontWoff}) format('woff');
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
    }
`;
```

and this is my index.js where I import my font and styles :

```
import GlobalStyles from './styles/globalStyles';
import GlobalFonts from './fonts/Fonts';

ReactDom.render((
  <React.Fragment>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalFonts />
      <GlobalStyles />
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Main />
      </Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.Fragment>
), document.getElementById('tetris'));
```

With this, I can see the font is given to my div, but I have no change, and my font does not appear in the Network flow. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know these fonts, but if they are any different, add them in two times
in this example i took it like one of them was italic

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: 'ClickerScript';
        src: url(${NameOfYourFontWoff}) format('woff'),
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
    }
 @font-face {
        font-family: 'ClickerScript';
        src: url(${NameOfYourFontWoff2}) format('woff2'),
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: italic;
    }
```

Let me know if it works and for clarification, you don't see any of these font loaded (even failed) in the request tab ?

Comment: hi , thx for your answer and your time. Unfortunatly, nothing change with this.

Comment: could you lock the network tab and the console tab where you select an item to see the font family ?

Comment: this is my body style :

```
body {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: roadRage;
    background-color: #060C21;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}
```